# Individual iCloud passwords randomly/occasionally disappear

Tags: macos, icloud, safari, password, keychain

Every few months I notice a password or two I need is no longer in the iCloud passwords list found in Mac Safari preferences.

This issue has happened on several (6+) occasions over the past year.
The passwords that have disappeared were definitely there originally because I have a backup list of passwords from February, which show that the passwords lost were originally saved.

Has anybody else encountered this?
How can I prevent this from happening?